# Linux Mint site?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange

I'm a Linux Mint user, and I use Ask Ubuntu a lot. However, some questions about the Mint GUI don't fit there. Should we start a Mint site?

Comment: About the downvotes: [Voting is different on meta. On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @Glorfindel OK, thanks! That explains the downvotes.

Comment: You shouldn't be asking Mint questions on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @TheWanderer The CLI is the same, so anything non-GUI is fine on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Not everything is the same. You can install Cinnamon on Ubuntu, but that doesn't make it Mint. There are other packages that can and do differ. https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/684/274320

Comment: Should I close this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you shouldn't; there is already a generic [Unix & Linux site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) and it has over 3,000 questions about [Linux Mint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux-mint) already. I'm pretty sure that if you'd start a new proposal on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com) it would be closed as a duplicate of an existing site.

Comment: Why does Ubuntu get its own site? Was that before Unix & Linux?

Comment: I was posting a comment to the same effect (minus the A51 reference); I wasn't sure from the description whether Mint GUI would have been on-topic.

Comment: Granted, most questions aren't about the GUI, but [some of them are](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Blinux-mint%5D+gui).

Comment: About why Ask Ubuntu is a separate site: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/18275/606366

Comment: The Mint site would be dedicated to the Mint-specific stuff, which is mostly the GUI. Also, those are apparently mostly about starting it. This would be about stuff like the Update Manager, the xApps, etc.

Comment: elementary has one too: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/, albeit still beta. I have seen the same argument against it when it was initiated on Area 51 but it's there. I see no difference between the elementary and the mint status in abstract terms, but the reasons at work are merely practical, related to real demand; elementary had limited coverage on U&L and had nothing similar to https://forums.linuxmint.com/. As for askubuntu, I think Canonical wanted it.

Comment: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=161699